# How to auto-mount a file server on home network machines

Tags: windows, networking, macos, file-server

I have three computers at home: Win7, Mountain Lion (OSX), and Snow Leopard (OSX).

I want to setup a server on my homenetwork so that I can collaboratively transfer files to/from the server from any of the three machines. Ideally, at the computer startup time the server would be mounted automatically.

I've successfully done this on my windows box, however, I'm not able to do this on the OSX Machines.

**Questions**

- Can someone guide me through this process? Do I need special scripts on OSX that mount the drive at start-up time?
- Would having multiple OS versions of OSX make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, you can use Connect to Server... under the Go menu to mount the network volume, and opt to store credentials in your keychain.  Then once the drive is mounted, you can create an alias to it (Make Alias under File menu, or command-L).  That will allow you to double-click the alias and have the drive mount when you need it.

You can also set up the drive to automatically remount on login, here is a good set of instructions for that:

http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/20/map-a-network-drive-on-a-mac/

> ```
> From the Finder, hit Command+K
> Enter the path to the network drive you want to map, ie: smb://networkcomputer/networkshare and click ‘Connect’
> Enter your login credentials and click “OK”
> The drive is now mounted, but continue on to map for system reboot persistence
> Now enter into System Preferences, from the Apple menu
> Click on ‘Accounts’
> Click on “Login Items”
> Click on the + button to add another login item
> Locate the network drive you previously mounted and click “Add”
> Exit out of System Preferences
> ```

This should work on Mac OS X 10.3 and later.

Comment: Make that 10.3+ for which it should work ;-)